# Rectangular support vs Triangular support

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

In the context of Bivariate distributions; can someone shed some light into this statement?

> Whenever
>   the support $S$ is not “rectangular,” the random variables must be dependent, because $S$ cannot then equal the product set $\{(x, y): x ∈ S_X, y ∈ S_Y\}$

My own conclusion is that for a 'rectangular support'
each $x$ variable has the same number of corresponding $y$ variables.
So for instance,

$S_X = \{x : x = 0, 1, 2\}$ and $S_Y = \{y: y = 3,4,5\}$

Then if the joint pmf is such that:$S_{XY} = \{(0,3), (1,4), (2,5)\}$ we have a rectangular support. Since we have a 1-1 relationship between $x$ and $y$ variables (it need not be 1-1, it could be $2-2, 15-15$, etc).

BUT

If the joint pmf is such that $S_{XY} = \{(0,3), (0,4), (1,5), (2,5)\}$, then we have a triangular support, since here $x=0$ has two corresponding $y-$values, but $x=1,2$ only have $1$ corresponding $y-$ values each.

Is my understanding rock-solid brahs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true that rectangular support means that  ``each $x$ variable have the same number of $y$ variables."

It means that the pdf is defined and non-zero on some rectangular region. For example, if your pdf lives on the region where $0<x<1$ and $0<y<5$, it lives on a rectangular region. If your pdf lives on $0<x<1$ and $y>0$, it still lives on a rectangular region-- just a really tall rectangle!

On the other hand, if your pdf lives on the space where $0<x<y<1$, it lives on a triangular region and such random variables can not be independent. (By the way, random variables living on a rectangular region do not have to be independent.)

[image: rectangular versus not rectangular]

Comment: thanks for the clarification rubarb! this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: You're welcome!